# how to update json file from android app?

Tags: android, json

I have a json file on my server that i would like to update from my android app. And by update I mean I want to add new data to my .json file that is on my server. 
Ps. I dont want to download the .json file and then update it. Any other way is appreciated

Comment: you can't write to a json file that is on the server directly you need to have it locally

Comment: If you don't want to get the content of the file locally, open it on server. Do some server side coding, to create a REST based api, which accepts GET/POST call. You can send data with your HTTP request. When you make rest request to a specific URL, read the JSON file and put in the data you want to in your JSON file. So in short you might need to write some sever side code to achieve that.

Comment: Pass the required data from the app and update the json on server with api having code to add object to Json

Comment: Might be nice if you even mentioned what server side technology stack you are using

Comment: Oh thanks everyone. Could anyone show me a guide to set up the server it?